# Reference a head and a tie - What am I

Tags: riddle, anagram

> You might hear my term in sports or an online game
>
> If I loose my 3rd letter I might reference a head or a tie
>
> Switch my first two letters, read me backwards and read me reverse. Oh
>   what a shame.
>
> Leave my first letter and keep my vowels too, then I definitely won't
>   sound dry.

What am I?

Comment: Is "read me backwards and read me reverse" intentional?

Comment: @MohitJain, Actually for this one, yes, it is intentional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word is

> server

In sports or an online game,

> The server is the person serving a volleyball or tennis ball, or the computer system the game is running on.

If you remove the 3rd letter it becomes

> sever -- you could speak of a severed head (ew) or severing ties with someone.

If you switch the first two letters and read it backwards it becomes

> revrse

Remove all the consonants but the first letter and it becomes

> see, which sounds like "sea".

Comment: damn, I was somehow trying to make "serve" work....